# Angular4 & D3 networkgraph

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

Hello guys im currently looking into creating a simple D3 networkgraph with typescript(Angular 4). Like this one: http://bl.ocks.org/jose187/4733747

However I am struggling trying to translate into TypeScript with Angular4. I already got D3 integrated into my project and its working however, implementing the logic is becoming a hassle since there is no real tutorial or usefull guid for Angular 4/2 + D3.js.

[What ive got so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMQs5.png)

So im wishing someone could help me with this or give some advice or help, because im a new typescript/angular developer.

Comment: Please copy your code `https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMQs5.png` here so people will see it

Comment: The example is in d3v2, you are probably having d3v4 which has a lot of changes. Referer [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md) or find an example in `v4`

Comment: Thanks a lot people I will have a look at the already existing example provided!